# Forwarding Monitor Parallel computation

Tags: parallelization, neural-networks, monitoring

I'm experimenting with training neural networks.

```
Map[NetTrain[NetInitialize@#, trdata] &, {net1, net2}]
```

shows the Training Progress monitor on each calculation. But

```
ParallelMap[NetTrain[NetInitialize@#, trdata] &, {net1, net2}]
```

doesn't show those.

Is it possible to forward the Training Process monitors to the front end in a parallel computation?

Comment: On my machine (11.0.1), `NetTrain` already uses all CPU cores. I would expect `ParallelMap` to result in reduced performance compared to a serial run.  Why do you want to parallelize manually?  Do you have any evidence that it helps?

Comment: @Szabolcs I ran a test on my machine: singel train `~220s`, 4 nets parallel `~400s` each. It might be influenced by Hyperthreading and Turbo boost of my i7 processor.